# I am getting a null reference exception when I use a class inside of a class

Tags: c#

I am using a class that has a member of another class (all of the members are strings), and when I try to set a value I get a null reference exception. Can anyone help me? I'm still kind of new to classes.

Here are my two classes:

```
    public class MergeFields
    {
        public string FNAME { get; set; }
        public string LNAME { get; set; }
        public string CITY { get; set; }
        public string STATE { get; set; }
    }


    public class Member
    {
        public string email_Address { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public MergeFields merge_fields { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is where I set the value of CITY:

```
Member Person = new Member();
string cityTest = "New York";
person.merge_fileds.CITY = cityTest; //This is where I get the exception
```

Am I missing something stupid obvious? Or is this just not possible?

Comment: `person.merge_fileds = new MergeFields();` first

Comment: Well, you never set `merge_fields` to anything, so it's null.

Comment: `public MergeFields merge_fields { get; set; } = new MergeFields();`

Comment: This is not a duplicate: this poster is asking why he is getting the error, that is, what is the mistake in his code; the "duplicate" is asking what the error means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are. You have two choices:

1. Explicit class initialization:

   `person.merge_fileds = new MergeFields();`
2. Implicit class initialization:

   ```
   public class Member
   {
      public string email_Address { get; set; }
      public string status { get; set; }
      public MergeFields merge_fields { get; set; }

      public Member(){
         merge_fields = new MergeFields();
      }
   }
   ```

Using second approach allows you not to change the code for assigning.

Answer (score 1):

You neeed to initialize first

```
person.merge_fileds = new MergeFields{CITY = cityTest};
```

Comment: If you spend more than 5 minutes answering C# questions, you should know that anything to do with a null reference exception is a duplicate...

Comment: Right, should have done that. Thanks :)